# Android emulator with custom build does not accept keyboard entry

Tags: android-emulator, keyboard, emulation, qemu

I have a custom Android image using a custom built goldfish kernel. I have been using the Emulator for SW development.

```
emulator -kernel out/target/product/atom/kernel
```

When I upgraded to SDK 20 I no longer get keyboard input from neither the host nor the graphic keyboard. This used to work. I have seen the comments about setting the hw.keyboard property=yes.  I am not able to find a sequence of operations that work.

a) try and launch the emulator and force my hardware config

```
emulator -verbose -kernel out/target/product/atom/kernel -qemu -android-hw /home/jgrecco/work/ics-4.0.4/out/target/product/atom/hardware-qemu.ini
```

The hardware-qemu gets overwritten and the hw.keyboard option is no.

b) Create an AVD and have it load my custom kernel and image

```
ex: android create avd --force -b x86 -n aal_emul -t 3

emulator -kernel out/target/product/atom/kernel -show-kernel  @aal_emul
```

But have not been able to get the AVD to boot my custom image. It seems to boot a default image.  I've tried copying over the img files but no luck

c) Tried modifying the default hardware.ini settings 
ics-4.0.4/external/qemu/android/avd/hardware-properties.ini with no effect.

many many other variants.

If someone could make any of the solutions above work or tell me one that will I would appreciate it.  BTW this is for x86 atom.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

After much experimentation, Googling,  lots of cursing inaccurate (out of date) documentation and updating all of my sources (fighting with repo sync hangs – rant off), I’ve figured out a work around. I thought I would post this for the benefit of others.

The basic problem was that after upgrading to SDK 20 I no longer could input to an application using ANY means (real or emulator keyboard).  This only occurred when loading my own custom image "lunch #; emulator -kernel out/target/product/...". None of the attempts to override the hw.keyboard property as described above worked for me.

The work around I’ve found  is to change the setting in the emulator at runtime.  Settings->Language & input->default_Hardware Physical keyboard (OFF).    While I can’t use the host keyboard I can now use the emulator keyboard for input.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `'hw.keyboard=true'` in the file `config.ini` which exists alongside `hardware-qemu.ini`.
This overrides the default value in `hardware-qemu.ini` and shouldn't be overwritten.